# create new table with columns populated from the field name of another table

Tags: oracle

I need a new table A with columns populated from the field name of another table B. If table B has 50 rows with value of the field name, then table A should have 50 columns with the same name.

Comment: You mean a PIVOT?

Comment: @OldProgrammer, yeah, kind of

Comment: @user2102665 can you give an example?

Comment: "... then table A should have 50 columns with the same name". Huh? That won't work. A table can't have two (or more) columns having the same name. Perhaps you should post a simple example which illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding you are trying to dynamically create column based on data on another table.

You can do this via execute immediate in PL/SQl block. Here is an example

```
DECLARE
CURSOR C_COLMNS IS SELECT DISTINCT FIELD_NAME FROM B;
BEGIN 
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE A(NAME VARCHAR2(10))';
   COMMIT;
   FOR FN IN C_COLMNS
   LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE A ADD '||FN.FIELD_NAME||' VARCHAR2(50)';
      COMMIT;
   END LOOP;
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE A DROP COLUMN NAME';
END;
/
```